# How can I create a packet capture file on a headless server for a single process?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, headless

I'm writing a python script on a headless server, and I'd like to see the packet capture output for the script.

I can't run ettercap or Wireshark on the server as there is too much other noise (besides, wireshark is a GUI tool). I do  have sudo access, however.

Is there any way that I can capture the packets generated by that script only? Preferably in a format that can be loaded into Wireshark (Not mandatory, however, I can trudge through the text if necessary)

Comment: Try tcpdump and some filters.

Comment: or TShark, bundled with Wireshark: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5800/wireshark-from-command-line

Answer (score 4):

Wireshark has a command line utility. I have used it on remote computers where I only had console access, it works quite well. Takes only a few minutes of reading the parameters to learn how to use it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark>dumpcap.exe -h
Dumpcap 1.10.3 (SVN Rev 53022 from /trunk-1.10)
Capture network packets and dump them into a pcapng file.
See http://www.wireshark.org for more information.

Usage: dumpcap [options] ...

Capture interface:
  -i <interface>           name or idx of interface (def: first non-loopback),
                           or for remote capturing, use one of these formats:
                               rpcap://<host>/<interface>
                               TCP@<host>:<port>
  -f <capture filter>      packet filter in libpcap filter syntax
  -s <snaplen>             packet snapshot length (def: 65535)
  -p                       don't capture in promiscuous mode
  -B <buffer size>         size of kernel buffer in MB (def: 2MB)
  -y <link type>           link layer type (def: first appropriate)
  -D                       print list of interfaces and exit
  -L                       print list of link-layer types of iface and exit
  -d                       print generated BPF code for capture filter
  -k                       set channel on wifi interface <freq>,[<type>]
  -S                       print statistics for each interface once per second
  -M                       for -D, -L, and -S, produce machine-readable output

RPCAP options:
  -r                       don't ignore own RPCAP traffic in capture
  -u                       use UDP for RPCAP data transfer
  -A <user>:<password>     use RPCAP password authentication
  -m <sampling type>       use packet sampling
                           count:NUM - capture one packet of every NUM
                           timer:NUM - capture no more than 1 packet in NUM ms
Stop conditions:
  -c <packet count>        stop after n packets (def: infinite)
  -a <autostop cond.> ...  duration:NUM - stop after NUM seconds
                           filesize:NUM - stop this file after NUM KB
                              files:NUM - stop after NUM files
Output (files):
  -w <filename>            name of file to save (def: tempfile)
  -g                       enable group read access on the output file(s)
  -b <ringbuffer opt.> ... duration:NUM - switch to next file after NUM secs
                           filesize:NUM - switch to next file after NUM KB
                              files:NUM - ringbuffer: replace after NUM files
  -n                       use pcapng format instead of pcap (default)
  -P                       use libpcap format instead of pcapng

Miscellaneous:
  -N <packet_limit>        maximum number of packets buffered within dumpcap
  -C <byte_limit>          maximum number of bytes used for buffering packets wi
thin dumpcap
  -t                       use a separate thread per interface
  -q                       don't report packet capture counts
  -v                       print version information and exit
  -h                       display this help and exit

Example: dumpcap -i eth0 -a duration:60 -w output.pcapng
"Capture packets from interface eth0 until 60s passed into output.pcapng"

Use Ctrl-C to stop capturing at any time.
```

Answer (score 4):

[Yes, you can with iptables and dumpcap.](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/NFLOG) Summary:

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --pid-owner 1000 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
# iptables -A INPUT -m connmark --mark 1 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 30 
# iptables -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 30 
# dumpcap -i nflog:30 -w pid-1000.pcap
```

This will capture all traffic with process ID 1000. These command have to be run on the host itself (which is where the PID info is available).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to pipe `dumpcap` output over SSH into wireshark running in on your local machine.

```
wireshark -k -i <(ssh -l USER REMOTEHOST "dumpcap -i lo -P -w - -f 'not tcp port 22'")
```

This will open an instance of wireshark locally displaying traffic from the remote machine. You will likely want to amend the filter `not tcp port 22` to prevent piping too much traffic across the network.